# How to handle AggregateException of a plain task (with FSharpx.Core)?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

My question is a two-fold one, I believe. In the following, how to catch `AggregateException` and print it out when

1. The tasks are `Task` objects, not `Task<void>` ones?
2. When the tasks `Task<_>` ones (e.g. `Task<void>`?

Here's s short, somewhat fabricated snippet. The `taskGenerator` in the following snippet emulates some external C# library function that either returns an array of `Tasks` or one `Task` combined with `Task.WhenAll`.

I'm not sure how should I catch the resulting `AggregateException` and print it in either generic or non-generic case. Then other problem is the interaction with the non-generic one which I need to cast to satisfy `FSharpx`, but then `Ignore` throws the exception which may not be desired.The `Ignore` function is from [here](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/f-28-integrating-with-task-parallel-library/), and I believe it's a rather used way to transform a `Task` to `Task<unit>`.

```
open FSharpx
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System
open FSharpx.Task

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =  
    let Ignore(task:Task) =
        let continuation (t: Task): unit =
            if t.IsFaulted then
                raise t.Exception
            else
                ()
        task.ContinueWith continuation

    let taskGenerator() =
        let task = TaskBuilder(scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default)
        //The following just emulates an external source that returns a bunch of plain
        //tasks. It could return also one plain task one would like to await for (e.g.
        //this exernal, simulated source could call Task.WhenAll.)
        task {
             let tasks =
                [|1; 2; 3;|]
                |> Seq.map(fun i ->
                    let taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<unit>()
                    taskSource.SetException(new ArgumentException("Argh!"))
                    taskSource.Task :> Task)
            return! Task.WhenAll(tasks) |> Ignore
        }

    let final() =
        let task = TaskBuilder(scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default)
        task {
            let! a = taskGenerator()
            a |> ignore
        }

    try        
        let finalRes = final()
        finalRes |> ignore
    with :? AggregateException as aex ->
        printfn "%A" aex


    let x = System.Console.ReadLine()

    0
```

Comment: I'd use `Task.run` instead of catching exceptions ( https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L918 )

Comment: Indeed, in this case it looks like an appropriate action to take. One can just "pass along" the tasks and take it somewhere. Then if one is in control of the tasks, maybe it's better to "envelope" the tasks with try-catch and return ``Options`` or some other domain constructs. I think the mental pain I feel is mostly due to the plain ``Tasks``. By the way, sorry for the long delay, I've been crazy busy lately. If you'd care to promote your commento as an answer, I could accept it.